# can we use singleton pattern for login function? what is the reason of that?

Tags: design-patterns

According to the singleton design patterns, google mentioned , we can use singleton design pattern for login function. what is the reason of that ? because in singleton which can only create one instance but people can login to the system simultaneously more than one.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right. But using Singleton for creating one and unique instance doesn't meen you can't login to the system simultaneously, the second login which will have place will not enter the block "***if***" of the generic structure of the **pattern**. The instance is already created so we use its information rather than using global variables that will respectively contain for example its name, address ... [Singleton Class in Java from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARToG.png)